# ASP.NET Web-api core: Handling client connections problems and find conflicts

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

### Background

I have a web api server (asp.net core v2.1) that serve some basic operation, like managing entities on the server. This is the interface:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("create")]
public async Task<ActionResult<NewEntityResponse>> Create(CreateEntityModel model)
{
    // 1) Validate the request.
    // 2) Create a new row on the database
    // 3) Return the new entity in response.
}
```

The user running this REST method in this way:

```
POST https://example.com/create

Content-Type: application/json

{
    "firstName": "Michael", 
    "lastName": "Jorden"
}
```

And getting response like this:

```
Status 200

{
    "id": "123456" // The newly created entity id
}
```

### The Problem

When sending thousands of requests like this, at some point it will fail because of network connections. When connection fails, it can leads us into two different situations:

- The network call was ended on the way to the server - In this case, the server don't know about this request. Therefore, the entity wasn't created. The user just have to send the same message again.
- The network call was sent from the server to back to the client but never rich the destination - In this case the request was fulfill completely, but the client don't aware for this. The expected solution is to send the same request again. In this case, it will create the same entity **twice** - and this is the problem.

### The Requested Solution

I want to create an generic solution for web-api that "remmeber" which commands it already done. if he got same request twice, it's return HTTP status code `Conflict`.

### Where I got so far

I thought to add the client an option to add a unique id to the request, in this way:

```
POST https://example.com/create?call-id=XXX
```

Add to my server a new filter that check if the key `XXX` is already fulfill. If yes, return `Conflict`. Otherwise - continue.

Add another server filter that checks the response of the method and marking it as "completed" for further checks.

The problem with this solution on concurrency calls. If my method takes 5 seconds to be returned and the client sent the same message again after 1 second - it will create two entities with same data.

### The Questions:

1. Do you think that this is good approach to solve this problem?
2. Do you familiar with ready to use solutions that doing this?
3. How to solve my "concurrency" problem?
4. Any other tips will be great!

thanks.

Comment: Good questions, however , it sounds you are inventing a new WS-transation .

Comment: not saying this is the complete or best solution. but have you looked into dbcontext pooling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isnt the easiest solution to make the REST action **[idempotent](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/idempotency.html)**?

I mean by that: the call should check if the resource already exists and either create a new resource if it doesnt or return the existing if it does?

Comment: i would recomment that too, you could easily add a "client reference" e.g. a guid or some hash and when the client retries the same request (with that same ID) the server knows it already did that. these IDs could be stored in redis for fast access.

Comment: Its an option in some cases, but not always. In this strategy, the user should know the id of the element. In my case, the user dont know the ID before the object created...

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever Not really,the server should detect duplicates (based on the content of the resource, not the ID) and refuse to create a new one but instead return the existing resource. To stick to your example, if 'Michael Jorden' is posted, the server should check if that person exists with that name, if so, return the existing instead of creating. Offcourse with persons it might not be that easy since multiple people with that name could exist, but im assuming more information is posted than just first/last name :)

Comment: After thinking on it a while. I agree with your solution. You convinced me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just figure it up how to make it right. So, I implemented it by myself and share it with you.

In order to sync all requests between different servers, I used Redis as cache service. If you have only one server, you can use `Dictionary<string, string>` instead.

This filter do:

1. Before processing the request - add a new empty value key to Redis.
2. After the server processed the request - store the server response in Redis. This data will be used when the user will ask again for same request.

   public class ConflictsFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
   {
       const string CONFLICT_KEY_NAME = "conflict-checker";
       static readonly TimeSpan EXPIRE_AFTER = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

   ```
   private static bool ShouldCheck(ActionDescriptor actionDescription, IQueryCollection queries)
   {
       return queries.ContainsKey(CONFLICT_KEY_NAME);
   }

   private string BuildKey(string uid, string requestId)
   {
       return $"{uid}_{requestId}";
   }

   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
   {
       if (ShouldCheck(context.ActionDescriptor, context.HttpContext.Request.Query))
       {
           using (var client = RedisConnectionPool.ConnectionPool.GetClient())
           {
               string key = BuildKey(context.HttpContext.User.GetId(), context.HttpContext.Request.Query[CONFLICT_KEY_NAME]);
               string existing = client.Get<string>(key);
               if (existing != null)
               {
                   var conflict = new ContentResult();
                   conflict.Content = existing;
                   conflict.ContentType = "application/json";
                   conflict.StatusCode = 409;

                   context.Result = conflict;
                   return;
               }
               else
               {
                   client.Set(key, string.Empty, EXPIRE_AFTER);
               }
           }
       }

       base.OnActionExecuting(context);
   }

   public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
   {
       base.OnResultExecuted(context);
       if (ShouldCheck(context.ActionDescriptor, context.HttpContext.Request.Query) && context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 200)
       {
           string key = BuildKey(context.HttpContext.User.GetId(), context.HttpContext.Request.Query[CONFLICT_KEY_NAME]);
           using (var client = RedisConnectionPool.ConnectionPool.GetClient())
           {
               var responseBody = string.Empty;
               if (context.Result is ObjectResult)
               {
                   ObjectResult result = context.Result as ObjectResult;
                   responseBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Value);
               }

               if (responseBody != string.Empty)
                   client.Set(key, responseBody, EXPIRE_AFTER);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }

The code is executed only if the query `?conflict-checker=XXX` is exists.

This code is provide you under MIT license.

Enjoy the ride :)